# (java)¿como hacer overriding al toString con 2 constructores?

Tags: java, constructor

tengo el siguiente codigo de java:

```
public class testPaciente {
public static void main( String[] args ){
    Scanner datos = new Scanner(System.in);
    String nombre;
    int edad;
    int dni;
    char genero;
    float peso;
    float altura;

    System.out.print("Escriba su nombre: ");
    nombre=datos.next();
    System.out.print("Escriba su edad: ");
    edad=datos.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Escriba su genero: ");
    genero=datos.next().charAt(0);
    System.out.print("Escriba su peso: ");
    peso=datos.nextFloat();
    System.out.print("Escriba su altura: ");
    altura=datos.nextFloat();

    Paciente paciente1 = new Paciente(nombre,edad,genero);
    Paciente paciente2 = new Paciente(nombre,edad,genero,peso,altura);
    System.out.println(paciente2);
}
```

y el siguiente toString:

```
 public String toString(){

return ("Nombre: "+this.nombre+"\nEdad: "+this.edad+"\nDNI: "+generarDNI()+"\nGénero: "+this.genero+"\nPeso: "+this.peso+"\nEstatura: "+this.altura+"\nIMC: "+calcularIMC());
}
```

quiero encontrar la manera de que se ejecute el primer constructor, lo que hago es imprimir la informacion de cada paciente, pero el segundo constructor siempre se ejecuta, no veo manera de introducir solo los datos de nombre, edad y genero para que use el primer constructor, luego el toString deberia imprimir solo esos 3 datos, cosa que todavia no logro

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Como es la definicion de la clase paciente?

Comment: Que tiene que ver el constructor con el toString??? me parece que estas confundiendo las ideas. Podes mostrar tu clase paciente?

Comment: El segundo constructor se ejecuta porque está en la antepenúltima linea de código. Prueba con **System.out.println(paciente1);** a ver si te sirve.

Comment: Hola @CarlosMoncayo agregué un método donde puedes validar no mostrar cualquier valor que no agruegues en el constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal y como tienes la pregunta, confundes conceptos. Creo que lo que quieres es que el toString() imprima todos los datos que tiene informados. Tal y como lo tienes, imprime los de Paciente2 correctamente pero en el paciente1 te saldrán varios campos a null. Entendiendo que este es el problema, sustituye el toString por este código

```
public String toString(){

    if(this.peso != null && this.altura !=null)
    {
        return ("Nombre: "+this.nombre+"\nEdad: "+this.edad+"\nDNI: "+generarDNI()
               +"\nGénero: "+this.genero+"\nPeso: "+this.peso+"\nEstatura: "+this.altura
               +"\nIMC: "+calcularIMC());
    }
    else
    {
        return ("Nombre: "+this.nombre+"\nEdad: "+this.edad+"\nDNI: "+generarDNI()
               +"\nGénero: "+this.genero);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tratas de realizar es imprimir los valores de estos objetos:

```
Paciente paciente1 = new Paciente(nombre,edad,genero);
Paciente paciente2 = new Paciente(nombre,edad,genero,peso,altura);
System.out.println(paciente1);
System.out.println(paciente2);
```

Para imprimir el valor de un objeto en java, si deseas obtener información del objeto puedes sobreescribir el método toString(), y agregar los valores que serán retornados al llamar este método.

**Sobreescribe el método en tu clase `Paciente`**

```
@Override
public String toString(){

return "Nombre: "+this.nombre+"\nEdad: "+this.edad+"\nDNI: "+generarDNI()+"\nGénero: "+this.genero+"\nPeso: "+this.peso+"\nEstatura: "+this.altura+"\nIMC: "+calcularIMC();

}
```

De esta forma al imprimir la instancia podrás obtener su información.

**Ahora si no deseas imprimir los valores que no definas como en este caso:**

```
Paciente paciente1 = new Paciente(nombre,edad,genero);
    Paciente
```

**puedes validar dentro del método de esta forma de acuerdo a sus tipos:**:

```
    @Override
    public String toString(){

      return (nombre!=null?"Nombre: "+this.nombre:"")+(edad>0?"\nEdad: "+this.edad:"")+(generarDNI()>0?"\nDNI: "+generarDNI():"")+(genero!=null?"\nGénero: "+this.genero:"")+(peso>0.0f?"\nPeso: "+this.peso:"")+(altura>0.0f?"\nEstatura: "+this.altura:"")+(calcularIMC()>0.0f?"\nIMC: "+calcularIMC():"");


    }
```